# Add Angular-ui through bower

Tags: angularjs, gulp, angular-ui, bower

I'd like to use the angular-ui filters package and I'd like to install it through bower. I've run `bower install --save angular-ui` which installs it and inserts it into the `bower.json` file.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to actually import the files into the project. I've already got `ui.bootstrap` in there, I can't find any instructions to install the filters part.

Comment: In the first statement you say that it installs it. And in the second statement you mention that it does not import the file - what do you mean by not importing?

Comment: Bower won't reference files in your project. It will simply download. Referencing it in your project is your responsibility.

Comment: That's what the --save argument does, it adds it to the `bower.json` file which includes it in my index.html automatically. I'm using the angular-gulp yeoman.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen issues where the folder already exists in bower_components and so bower assumes that its already there and doesn't add the files.

`bower uninstall angular-ui`

check that the angular-ui folder isn't in bower-components and if it is then delete it.

`bower install angular-ui --save`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it's still not working. It's adding it into the `bower.json` file but not into the index.html.

Comment: Ah if that's the case then the comments above are correct. You will either have to do it manually or use some tools like gulp/grunt to do it for you. Bower and NPM will just download the files but will not update your html  with the links.

Comment: to get it injected automatically in your index.html you should use gulp-wiredep